# Javascript to call Multiple SELECT fields Similar to inputBoxes[i] for Input Types

Tags: javascript, html

If there are Multiple `<input type...>` in a form , I am able to read them one by one in a loop as below.

```
for(var i=0; i<5; i++) 
{
 alert(inputBoxes[i].value)
}
```

But when i have Multiple  fields as below, how should call them in above loop ?

```
<select name="item_unit[]" id="item_unit"> ..... 
<select name="item_unit[]" id="item_unit"> .....
```

Please let me know the Javascript code.

Comment: Select elements have `value` property too, what is the problem here? Selecting the select elements?

Comment: This is not possible, since you've got 2 elements with the same `id` value here, which is not valid HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get all elements by tag name, in your case, 'select':

```
var myForm = document.getElementById("my-form-id"); 
var mySelects = myForm.getElementsByTagName('select');
for(var i=0; i<myselects.length; i++) 
{
   alert(myselects[i].value)
}
```

I've updated my sample using @ComFreek notes.

Comment: One small note: you can restrict the "search area" by calling `getElementsByTagName()` on a DOM element, for example, you could use `var myForm = document.getElementById("my-form-id"); var mySelects = myForm.getElementsByTagName(...`. This helps you add more select elements at a later time without worrying about your code.

Answer (score 0):

I would create an array containing the IDs of the elements you want to iterate:

```
var ids = ['item_unit1', 'item_uni2'];
ids.forEach(function (val) {
  var selectElement = document.getElementById(val);
});
```

Comment: I May not know how many <SELECT> will be there in form as it is dynamically ge
Please let me know the Javascript code.
update my question as well

Comment: @logan at0ma undeleted his post, which exactly does what you want.